# Running node-serialport in nw.js

Tags: node.js, nw.js, node-serialport

I am trying to run [node-serialport](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) in [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js). After following the [nw.js documentation concerning native modules](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Use%20Native%20Node%20Modules/), node-serialport seems to build just fine, and runs perfectly in a regular node process.

Unfortunately, I get the following error in the nw.js console window:

> {project_dir}\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:83 Uncaught Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46.

How can I run these together? Am I missing something obvious?

Note that I'm currently running:

- Windows 7 x64
- Node v4.4.4
- npm v2.4.1
- nw.js v0.15.0
- node-gyp v3.3.1
- serialport v3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I needed to update to the *Current* version of Node (v6.2.0) instead of the *LTS* version (v4.4.4). After updating and rebuilding serialport, everything works perfectly!